# Can't upgrade NPM packages with npm update/upgrade -g command

Tags: node.js, npm, archlinux

Running Archlinux + Gnome-Shell 3.20, NodeJS 5.10.1 NPM 3.8.6 version.

When running `sudo npm update -g` or `sudo npm upgrade -g` terminal gives

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /build/semver/src/semver-5.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /build/semver/src/semver-5.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /build/uglify-js/src/uglify-js-2.6.2.tgz
```

Same output for `sudo npm outdated -g`

While running `sudo npm install -g <package_name>` "updates" package no problem. Of course, I could install/upgrade each package individually but that defeats the purpose of npm update/upgrade -g command.

I've updated NPM to latest version via `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`
in hopes it would fix the issue like for many here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10165  but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be wrong, and this should help resolve your problem.

1. You should [fix your npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions), so you don't have to use `sudo` when you attempt to install a package globally using npm.
2. [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a tool that should be able to help you. There is likely an bug/corruption in your current node/npm version by looking at the GitHub issue, and the tool nvm will make it possible to change node versions while also fixing your `sudo` issue.

It is also possible that you installed npm using pacman rather than npm which could be why you can't upgrade correctly. You could the latest version of npm by using the command `pacman -S npm` which is a package available in the community repository.